Disambiguation of 先 in "締結先大学の学生の受入に伴う奨学金の支給"
I am working on a translation for research, and on a list of colleges from MEXT that have an agreement with international institutions, this is listed as one of the things that can be within an agreement:

締結先大学の学生の受け入れに伴う奨学金の支給

I know that this is the "Provision of a Scholarship that Accompanies A Student's Reception to the School in Agreement," but...with further reflection, I am not too sure anymore. I am particularly confused by the use of 先 here: As a suffix, it can refer to a destination, but my dictionary also indicates "the other party," and that seems more clear, but I do a reverse search of 締結先 online, and I get mixed results on how to translate it.
Does 締結先大学 refer to the "College within the Contract," or is there some nuance I am missing here?
EDIT: One of my main forms of confusion is in what side of the agreement gets the scholarship: This is made by MEXT, so I assume it refers to if a Japanese student goes to a university elsewhere, but I am unsure if some word nuance clarifies that.

I don't know if the context already disambiguated it, but did you notice that the sentence can be also parsed as 受け入れ of 締結先大学の学生?

締結先(の)大学 by itself is roughly the same as 契約中の大学 and just means "contracted/partner universities". The suffix -先 vaguely refers to a remote place or party.

行き先 destination
旅先 travel destination
応募先 organization to which one applies
就職先 company where one gets employed
仕事先 company where one works; workplace
バイト先 part-time workplace
注文先 organization from which one orders; supplier
送信先 person to whom one sends something; recipient
契約(締結)先 organization with which one has a contract; business partner

I think you can now see how "the other party" can be a valid translation in many contexts. See also: Why is 先 needed in アルバイト先で? and Meaning of 落着き先?
However, with this short text alone, it's unclear who gets the scholarship from which university. One likely interpretation is Japanese universities paying scholarships to students from outside Japan, but other possibilities can be considered.
